# Abide disable button and enable on validation in Zurb Foundation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm familiar with foundation abide a little, I was wondering how can I make the button disable and as the user type it gets validated and change the button to enable for submit.

**Form Example:**

```
<form data-abide>
  <div class="name-field">
    <label>Your name <small>required</small>
      <input type="text" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
    </label>
    <small class="error">Name is required and must be a string.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="email-field">
    <label>Email <small>required</small>
      <input type="email" required>
    </label>
    <small class="error">An email address is required.</small>
  </div>
  <input id="contactsubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="SEND" disabled>
</form>
```

**Disable:**

```
 <input id="contactsubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="SEND" disabled>
```

Now, as a user keep typing I would like it to be validated and if everything is correct enable the button, I know I can do this with jQuery `.change()`, But is there any standard way for abide?

I have done a lot of research, but I don't see what I'm trying to achieve, I can do it with bootstrap validation but not foundation.

#### UPDATE

Here is the plugin I use with bootstrap to achieve what I want, [Validator.js](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite what you are looking for because most forms can not be submitted unless your form is validated. Listening to see if the form validates and then enabling a submit button seems like its overkill.

Thus `data-abide` has this in mind when they created

> If a submit event is fired, a `valid.fndtn.abide` event is triggered
>   when the form is valid and an `invalid.fndtn.abide` event is triggered
>   when the form is invalid.

with that in mind i would enable the button and then

```
$(form)
 .on('invalid.fndtn.abide', function () {
  var invalid_fields = $(this).find('[data-invalid]');
 // tell the user that invalid fields must be fixed before submit
 })
 .on('valid.fndtn.abide', function () {
// your submit action here.
 });
```

There is an option in the `/foundation.abide.js` if you want to change out the validation works

```
 Abide.defaults = {
validateOn: 'fieldChange', // options: fieldChange, manual, submit
```

try changing it to manual and see if it works like '`abide : {live_validate : true, // validate the form as you go` that was in older versions

Comment: How about using [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)? instead of `.on()`, I try it but it keep validating on every change, I need it to do it once both are validated.

Comment: that won't work at all!- i have updated with some additional options

Comment: If you see this plugin, [Validator.js](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/), someone achieve what I want to do. As you scroll there is a disable option, which disable the button until form is validated. .

Comment: @Farhad but that is bootstrap. It doesn't have any thing to do with Foundation

Answer (score -4):

```
<a href="#" class="button disabled">Disabled Button</a>
```

Comment: This actually don't do anything. however adding `disabled` attribute does.

Comment: You should also add the validation to re enable it